# processing time for multiplication and exponentiation in pairing base cryptography

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature

I'm using the Boneh-Boyen-Shacham signature scheme and want to estimate complexity in my scheme.

As reported in "Scott M., Efficient Implementation of Cryptographic pairings", if we set parameters as: MNT curve, k=6 and p~160, then P(point mul)=0.6 ms and P(pairing)=4.5 ms.

These two measured times are used in many references. I found another reference (Lu, Rongxing, et al. "A dynamic privacy-preserving key management scheme for location-based services in vanets.") stating P(point exponentiation)=0.6 ms and P(pair)=4.5 ms.

I cannot understand how can I compute processing time for multiplication and exponentiation operations in BBS scheme in following image…

> [image: image copy of referred scheme]

**Questions:**

1. How many multiplications and exponentiations do we need, and
2. what is the processing time of each operation?

Comment: 1) How about counting them? 2) There is no general answer: Which platform (server, desktop, mobile, sensor,...), which language (C, Java,...), etc.?

Comment: counting number of elliptic curve point multiplication operations and number of exponentiation for computing time of signature. platform is a base station with a processing power at the desktop level with a low-level language like C. for example a sample is stated in "Scott M., Efficient Implementation of Cryptographic pairings": 32-bit 3GHz PIV, Tate pairing, k=6, p~160 bits MNT curve.

Comment: What about implementing the scheme using an existing pairing library?

Comment: I'm using this signature scheme in my protocol. I'm computing time complexity and i want to compare calculated formula for time complexity with the experimental results. So i need to know number of operations and time of them.

Comment: Yes, take some existing pairing library and benchmark the single required operations on your platform. Count the number of respective operations required by the BBS scheme, sum everthing together and there you go.

Comment: Thank you. could you please introduce a good library? I have another question, references "Scott M." and "Lu, Rongxing" Referring to one reference, have mentioned different expressions for exponentiation and multiplication. 
One of these two has stated multiplication= 0.6 and another has stated exponentiation=0.6 why??

Comment: You could use for example [pbc](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/) or [bnpairngs](https://code.google.com/p/bnpairings/). In a pairing setting with $e:G_1\times G_2 \mapsto G_T$ the groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ are elliptic curve groups, but many authors (such as in your figure) use multiplicative notation instead of the correct additive notation. So when multiplicative notation is used, the operation is exponentation while it is (scalar) multiplication if additive notation is used.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It was very useful for me. if you know a good reference with a complete and comprehensive explanation of pairing based cryptography, please introduce me..

Comment: Well it depends how familiar you are with elliptic curves. You may look at [this one](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~ajmeneze/publications/pairings.pdf) or [this one](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/165).

Comment: I know primary concepts. Thank you, link 1 is helpful.